# How to display data from the custom table in custom module magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, module

I need display data from the custom table in custom module magento 2

Comment: kindly show your module code. So that we can help you.

Comment: Thankz sir, I have solved this problem from http://www.mage-world.com/blog/how-to-use-model-and-collection-in-magento-2.html  .